# Retrieve data from @ManyToMany bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I'm struggling to find out how to retrieve data from a @ManyToMany relationship in spring. I'm running into the infinite recursion problem and have tried a few solutions, such as using @JsonIgnoreProperties, but to no avail.

A User can have many groups, and a group can have many users. I can add users to a group, but when it comes to retrieving all groups associated with a user, I get a stack overflow from the infinite recursion.

My GroupAccount class:

```
@Entity
public class GroupAccount {

//Private variables omitted for brevity

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "groupAccount_users",
                joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "groupAccount_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
private List<User> groupMembers = new ArrayList<>();

//Constructors, most getters, setters omitted for brevity

public void addUserToGroupParticipants(User user){
    groupMembers.add(user);
    incrementGroupMembers();
}

public void incrementGroupMembers() {
    numberOfMembers++;
}

public List<User> getGroupMembers(){
    return groupMembers;
}
}
```

My User class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

//Private variables omitted for brevity

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="groupMembers",
                        fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<GroupAccount> groupAccounts = new ArrayList<>();

//Constructors, most getters, setters omitted for brevity

public List<GroupAccount> getUsersAccounts() {
    return groupAccounts;
}
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to send a get request with the users ID and then to retrieve all GroupAccount objects that are associated with that user. Later down the line, I will want to be able to view all Users associated with a particular GroupAccount

Answer (score 0):

you should use `@JsonIgnore` annotation on `groupMembers` to avoid falling into infinite recursion.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
@JoinTable(name = "groupAccount_users",
                joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "groupAccount_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
private List<User> groupMembers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly how this works? Also, if I put @JsonIgnore above that relationship, does that stop me from getting all of the group members associated with a particular group further down the line?

Comment: This annotation prevents including groupMember's users Json format again when making Json as respond, and your second question's answer is yes it will stop

Comment: Okay well I can't use it if it will hinder my ability to get the Group members

Comment: You can get the group members and return it on your service layer

Answer (score 0):

You must override "toString" method in User class, an evaluation of this value cause stack overflow exception. You could debug it very easily and inspect it.

Comment: Did you excluded "groupAccounts"?

Comment: What do you mean? I override toString in both classes. Thats all I did

Comment: So you cause infinite loop in toString method because"GroupAccount" has users and "User" has group account, you must override toString in both classes excluding this relashionships.  So "GroupAccount" toString method must not include "groupMembers" field and "User" class toString method must not include "groupAccounts" field. This post has more detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938331/hibernate-stackoverflowexception-logging-manytomany-association

Comment: Okei, can you post stacktrace?

Comment: I have just changed it to a uni-directional relationship and have got it to work. It is not ideal but it will work fine